# Could tell me the cause and solution for error 'User data is limited to 16384 bytes' while launching a Windows instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

While launching the Windows instance at Initiating launches, the task got failed showing the below message,
               "User data is limited to 16384 bytes"
Could you provide the cause and the solution for the above in detail?
I am new to AWS.

Answer (score 5):

What AWS calls 'user data' is essentially a script that gets run when your instance boots for the first time (not on restart). Without more information, it sounds like whatever script you are providing for your instance user data, when base64 encoded, is too long for AWS limit. It may be worth revisiting exactly what is in the script and run it through a base64 encoder to verify its size. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html):

> When working with instance user data, keep the following in mind:
>
> User data must be base64-encoded. The Amazon EC2 console can perform the base64 encoding for you or accept base64-encoded input.
>
> User data is limited to 16 KB, in raw form, before it is base64-encoded. The size of a string of length n after base64-encoding is ceil(n/3)*4.

Comment: Just to clarify: the 16KB limit is actually on the **raw** user data - `User data is limited to 16 KB, in raw form, before it is base64-encoded`